# symfony2 dom_import_simplexml()

Tags: symfony

I have this error message :

> Warning: dom_import_simplexml(): Invalid Nodetype to import in
>   .../Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php
>   line 437

when I try to get the sf2 `Symfony/web/app_dev.php/` page on my web server after installing my sf2 framework.

How can I resolv this? Thanks

Comment: What is your PHP version? Your OS version? Are you using APC?

Answer (score 0):

It can be :

- an issue with PHP 5.4 installation [[Symfony Issue #3643](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3643)]
- an issue with APC breaking simplexml in PHP 5.4 [[PHP Bug #61956](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61956)]
- an outdated version of libxml [Check SimpleXML [requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.requirements.php), [installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.installation.php) and libxml [installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.installation.php)]

Comment: thanks for your response. I used Fedora 17 with PHP 5.4.3, apc, libxml and some others extensions.

Comment: I will investigate maybe theres some bugs because its a recent version of fedora. I change to Centos 6.2 and it's ok